# WSO2 Management Console Doesn't load after setting offset

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am testing WSO2 Servers on ec2 instance. When I start the server I can access the Management console by typing the `https://ip:9443/carbon` on the browser. Then I edit the `repository/conf/carbon.xml` as `<offset>10</offset>` and I start the server and following is the log,

```
[2015-03-16 09:31:37,354]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11121/jndi/rmi://localhost:10009/jmxrmi
[2015-03-16 09:31:37,354]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 API Manager-1.8.0
[2015-03-16 09:31:37,355]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 89 sec
[2015-03-16 09:31:38,850]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://172.31.x.x:9453/carbon/
[2015-03-16 09:31:38,851]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : http://172.31.x.x:9773/publisher
[2015-03-16 09:31:38,851]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://172.31.x.x:9773/store
[2015-03-16 09:31:39,081]  INFO - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Setting default carbon host for thrift key management service: 172.31.x.x
[2015-03-16 09:31:39,110]  INFO - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Started thrift key mgt service at port:10397
```

Then I tried with the same url I tried earlier but the port as 9453, but it doesn't load the management console. And no logs could be found. I tried the same scenario with `WSO2ESB` and `WSO2AM`, same result for both.

UPDATE:
When I search for open ports it gives the following,

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-x-x:~$ netstat -nltp | grep LISTEN | grep 94
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::9443                 :::*                    LISTEN      14076/java
tcp6       0      0 :::9453                 :::*                    LISTEN      14448/java
```

Comment: Have you opened the port (9453) of the EC2 server to be accessed from your browser.?

Comment: @Sumedha yes, I updated the answer with more information

Comment: Even-though the port is open inside the instance, you have to allow the outside (in this case your browser) to access that particular port. You can configure this via the Security Groups of that particular EC2 instance from the AWS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even-though the port is open inside the instance, you have to allow the outside (in this case your browser) to access that particular port. You can configure this via the Security Groups of that particular EC2 instance from the AWS console.